# Improve my Search engine

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, search-engine

I have tried to implement a simple search engine for my application. 
This is what I have done:

```
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX item_name_other_name_desc_index
    ON item (name,other_name,description)

public static function Search($string)
{   

    $delims = ',.; ';
        $word = strtok($string,$delims);
        while($word)
        {

           $result['accepted'][] = $word;                   
           $word = strtok($delims);

        }

          $string = implode(" ", $result['accepted']);

    $sql = 'SELECT item_id,name,other_name,description,price,discounted_price, thumbnail_photo,large_photo
    FROM item
    WHERE 
    MATCH(name,other_name,description)
    AGAINST(:string)' ;
    $parameters = array(':string' => $string);
    $result['items'] = DB::GetAll($sql,$parameters);
    return $result;
}
```

This works and searches for words only. Can anyone suggest me how can i improve it and how do i proceed if i want to search for strings like "Bi" which will show me results starting with that string.(for eg Bike..)

Comment: If you really plan to build on this more, or use it in a high-traffic application, you're probably better of replacing what you have with something like Lucene.  Otherwise you're doomed to rebuild Lucene's features yourself, poorly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the MySQL Fulltext-Search in Boolean mode.
This allows searches like 'Bi*'. You only would have to append the * to each accepted word and change the SELECT a bit.

```
SELECT item_id,name,other_name,description,price,
       discounted_price,thumbnail_photo,large_photo
FROM item
WHERE 
MATCH(name,other_name,description)
AGAINST(:string IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

where :string is filled with 'Bi*'

Comment: see the [link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) for Full-Text Search Functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wildcards like '%' and '_' ... for your example, having a search key like Bi% will include Bike and any other words that starts with 'Bi' in the result set.... and so on...

Comment: Will it be something like :
WHERE 
MATCH(name,other_name,description)
AGAINST(:string)
AND name LIKE  $string% ;

Comment: in SQL something like, WHERE key = 'Bi%', so from you example, i think you should append/concatenate '%' to $string like ... LIKE $string.'%'  ...

Comment: AND name LIKE ' . $string . '%'; Im getting the error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' at line 6. Can you help me please?

Comment: you forget to enclose the $string in qoutes, ... as a final sql expression, it should be , AND name like '".$string."%'" so it will appear as, AND name like 'valueOf$string%';